# SQLYog/MariaDB, table cells are 'dropdown boxes', I can't edit the cell, but i can do an update query from the same user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**Update: I didn't see anything in their JIRA issue tracker, so I rolled back to MariaDB 10.9 which I've been using on another server, and the issue went away. I'll definitely be posting to JIRA later. It might be a bug. I was having another issue as well with SQL Exports, varchar values weren't being quoted but probably wasn't related unless a bug being a bug in MariaDB.**

I'd still welcome insight if anyone has it.

---

**If I type in the cell, the box just opens to a blank selection. I can't type anything in. I can't edit the cell. I've never seen this happen before.**

Edit: I just found out that it's both dbs on this server... which is strange

A screenshot was important here to illustrate the problem, but pictured are two screenshots,

One has a table,

```
members_only | active | generate_static_page
           1 |      1 |                    1
```

And the other is a partial view of the same table with the dropdown-box open.

[image: a table depicting three uneditable columns]

[image: the same columns, with a 'dropdown box']

I've tried both restarting SQLYog and updating SQLYog, I've checked my permissions on the database. This is a testing database so I have full permissions.

I can't find the problem and googling isn't helping me.

Those columns all happen to be TINYINT, but varchar columns are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be present in version 13. I rolled back to version 12 and works fine.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This answer appears to be about PostgreSQL - On [this page](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=mariadb&p=mariadb&r=10.11.7&os=Linux&cpu=x86_64&pkg=tar_gz&i=systemd&m=heanet-ltd), there's no sign of 12 or 13 in any of the major version, release or sub-releases in the `MariaDB Server Version` dropdown. PostgreSQL, on the other hand, does currently (2024-03-12) have supported major versions 12 & 13.

Comment: @Vérace is the SQLYog version